# Filling a tree from the keyboard and output in the console

Tags: c#, binary-tree

I need to get the value of the node with the keyboard and display a tree in an orderly manner.
I try to keep the node value in the array, and then assign values to the array elements each node through the cycle.
Next, tree output to the console.

When the tree is created manually, everything works.
Assigning values through the array does not work.

```
    class Tree
        {
            class Node
            {
                public Node left;
                public Node right;
                public int value;
                public Node(Node left, Node right, int value)
                {
                    this.left = left;
                    this.right = right;
                    this.value = value;
                }
            }

            private Node _root;
            public Tree()
            {
                _root = null;
            }

            public void Add(int value)
            {
                _add(ref _root, value);
            }

            private void _add(ref Node node, int value)
            {
                if (node == null)
                {
                    node = new Node(null, null, value);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (node.value >= value)
                    {
                        _add(ref node.left, value);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _add(ref node.right, value);
                    }
                }
            }

            public void Print()
            {
                _print(_root);
            }

            private void _print(Node node)
            {
                if (node == null) return;
                _print(node.left);
                Console.WriteLine(node.value);
                _print(node.right);
            }

        }

}
```

Using in the program:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Tree t = new Tree();


        int n = 6;
        int[] strs = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            strs[i] = Console.Read();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            t.Add(strs[i]);
        }
        t.Print();
```

Without loop it works:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Tree t = new Tree();

            t.Add(1);
            t.Add(2);
            t.Add(6);
            t.Add(17);
            t.Add(21);
            t.Add(3);
            t.Add(8);

        t.Print();
    }
```

Comment: You should pay attention on what you add to array from the console.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
Just needed convert string to int:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Tree t = new Tree();

        int n = 6;
        int[] strs = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            strs[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            t.Add(strs[i]);
       }

        t.Print();

    }
```